# Design Suggestion, Tabhost, fragment, or anything else

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabhost

I have to implement the design something like this, and data will be changed on right and left section only not on top.

[a busy cat http://androgems.x10.mx/Images/Untitled.png](http://androgems.x10.mx/Images/Untitled.png)

There is a pattern,
On top portion selection --> only right screen will be changed, and 
On right portion selection --> only left portion will be changed.

How should I achieve this? any suggestion pls. 
I want to achieve it by no transition effects like in tabhost.
thanks in advance.